# Simple OData client - how to add proxy setting to OData client

Tags: .net, proxy, odata

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client to test OData API inside the company's network where the proxy is enabled. How to configure the OData client so that it can pass the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is no additional configuration needed for OData client. Just need to add the following line in web.config file. By the way, it is a .net mvc application.

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
 </system.net>
```